# SQL How to reach and check a query's elements in another query? (many-to-many)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

**User selects favorite malls, brands and sectors**

I try to show the campaigns which are valid for user's favorites.

Tables: Campaign(has malls and brand), MallCampaign, Mall, Brand, Sector, User, Favorite

For example; a user chose **X,Y,Z**(*Z:doesn't include Adidas shop*) malls; **Adidas**, **Levi's**, **Victoria's Secret** brands; **shoes** sector. So the user should only see **Adidas**'s campaign which is valid in **X,Y** malls.

How to combine these queries? Should I use JOIN or IF EXIST?

```
    SELECT mc.CampaignId, c.CampaignTitle
    FROM MallCampaign mc 
    JOIN Mall m ON m.MallId = mc.MallId
    JOIN Campaign c ON c.CampaignId = mc.CampaignId
    JOIN Brand b ON b.BrandId = c.BrandId


    SELECT FavoriteItemId AS FavoriteMalls
    FROM Favorite
    WHERE UserId = @UserId AND FavoriteItemType=1 

    SELECT FavoriteItemId AS FavoriteBrands
    FROM Favorite
    WHERE UserId = @UserId AND FavoriteItemType=3 

    SELECT FavoriteItemId AS FavoriteSectors
    FROM Favorite
    WHERE UserId = @UserId AND FavoriteItemType=2
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected results?  Your explanation does not do the problem justice.  For instance, you mention X, Y, Z and various brands in the text, but you have no corresponding entries in the sample SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you use `in`:

```
SELECT mc.CampaignId, c.CampaignTitle
FROM MallCampaign mc 
where mallid in (SELECT FavoriteItemId AS FavoriteMalls
                 FROM Favorite
                 WHERE UserId = @UserId AND FavoriteItemType=1
                ) and
      brandId in (SELECT FavoriteItemId AS FavoriteBrands
                  FROM Favorite
                  WHERE UserId = @UserId AND FavoriteItemType=3
                 ) and
      sectorid in (SELECT FavoriteItemId AS FavoriteSectors
                   FROM Favorite
                   WHERE UserId = @UserId AND FavoriteItemType=2 
                  )
```

This clarifies the intent of the query.  And, if you have an index on `Favorite(UserId, FavorteItemType, FavoriteItemId)` the performance should be quite good.

Comment: It looks the solution is like that. As it is quite complicated, difficult to test with data. Thanks anyway.